# If-else statement does not work inside a while loop

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I have a while loop, with an if statement inside. The if statement works fine, until I add an else statement. The problem is that when running the program, it jumps directly to the else statement, even when the condition inside the if statement is fulfilled. I can't seem to find the problem, and were hoping someone could help me...

Part of my code:

```
while(!filen.endOfFile()) {
    linje = filen.inLine();
    splitt = linje.split(",");  

    if (linje.toUpperCase().contains(fugl.toUpperCase())) {
        System.out.println(splitt[0] + ": ");
        System.out.println(splitt[1]);
        System.out.println(splitt[2]);
        System.out.println(splitt[3]);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Write something here..."); 
    }
}
```

EDIT: I tried to put the if statement as true, and now it shows the result, but the else statement is added at the bottom. I do not understand why this happens?

Comment: What are the values of `linje` and `fugl`?

Comment: It can't be possible that both `if` and `else` execute. Are you sure you are not seeing output from two different iteration?

Comment: Can you show us some sample input?

Comment: please, try to change the "if" condition to true, like `if (true) { .... } and see if works

Comment: System.out.println(linje.toUpperCase());   and   System.out.println(fugl.toUpperCase());  and compare values

Comment: The linje and fugl variables are String values :)

Comment: @user2795095: `fugl` and `linje` are `String` variables. They're values might be `"Foo"` or something else. Only you know their values.

Comment: Is it possible that every other line satisfies your `if` condition? In this case, you would get the false impression that the `println` statement in your `else` clause is always executed. Can you post an example of the file you are reading, and `fugl`'s value?

Comment: Fugl is an input value, it varies (logically) from the input given by the user. When I run the loop it searches to see if the word the user has given is found in a text file.

Comment: Then give us a text file example that shows the problem, along with the corresponding user input for `fugl`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when it happens it's because the source is not in-sync with the binaries. Try cleaning your project, and rebuild it for your IDE. Or maybe you can delete it from the IDE and import again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for JVM to go for executing else block even when the if condition is satisfied. Unless the condition result returns false value or the code is not compiled properly.

So try compiling the class & try again. Though it is not working as intended then put a absolute value "true" in the if condition, compile the class & check whether it executes if block or not.

Comment: I put the if as true, and now it prints the if statement but still also the else statement. I don't understand why...

Comment: Ah, I think I understand why now. My if statement reads through the file and prints out the ones that fit my search. It seems like the else statement prints out the ones that don't fit my search, therefore it always prints at the same time as the if statement. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
if (true) {
   System.out.println("Condition Satisfied");
} else {
   System.out.println("Condition not Satisfied");
}
```

If you have compiled the class properly then it will execute "*Condition Satisfied*" message on console every time.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid the else statement in printing always. You must delete the else statement. Only add another else if if there is another criteria you wanna search.